# Sorting array by numbers and putting into another array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, sorting, numbers

I want to sort an array of numbers and put into another array. The following code is what I found

```
IFS=$'\n' sorted=($(sort <<<"${array[*]}"))
unset IFS
echo "${sorted[*]}"
```

However, this does so by string

```
1 12 5 111 200 1000 10
1 10 1000 111 12 200 5
```

How do I get it sorted by number?

Comment: Just Use `sort -n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without modifying `IFS`.

```
$ p=(1 10 1000 111 12 200 5)
$ sorted_p=($(tr ' ' '\n' <<<"${p[@]}" | sort -n))
$ echo "${sorted_p[@]}"
1 5 10 12 111 200 1000
```

Comment: The second `tr` is not really necessary :)

Comment: That's right. I pasted from a test I was doing with `echo` at that moment. Edited...

Answer (score 2):

This code uses `\0` as delimiter and is therefore suitable even for sorting non-numerical arrays:

```
arr=(4 2 3 1 5)
sorted=()

while IFS= read -r -d '' item; do
    sorted+=("$item")
done < <(printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]}" | sort -zn)
```

In `bash` 4.4 you can also utilize `readarray`:

```
readarray -d '' sorted < <(printf '%s\0' "${arr[@]}" | sort -zn)
```